# Prove the map sending a matrix to it's inverse is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

Let $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ be the space of invertible $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{R}$. I have already proved that $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ and that it is not connected with the relative topology from $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$. How do I prove that the map $f:GL(n,\mathbb{R})\rightarrow GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ given by $f(x):=x^{-1}$ is continuous? 
Any help would be greatly apprecaited.

Additionally how do I prove that $g:GL(n,\mathbb{R})\times GL(n,\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ given by $g(x,y):=xy$ (matrix multiplication) is continuous, where we take the relative topology from $\mathbb{R}^{n^2} \times \mathbb{R}^{n^2} \cong \mathbb{R}^{2n^2}$?

Comment: Hint: Cramer's rule

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but can't this be simply answered by observing that an inverse is the quotient of the adjugate matrix and the determinant, and that the composition of continuous functions is continuous?

Comment: Yes the determinant map is continuous, but do you think I can assume the map sending a matrix to its adjugate is continuous?

Comment: adjugate consists of just determinants ...

Comment: Yes so it's a polynomial and therefore continuous! I've managed to do it, thanks for your response.

Comment: Do you know how I can also prove that the function is differentiable, when thought of as a function defined on an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$?

Comment: @jackwo it is basically a rational function. it is smooth on its domain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that the process you learned in high school to invert a matrix expresses the entries of the inverse matrix as rational functions of the entries of the original matrix.  (Remember that the determinant of a matrix is a polynomial in its entries.)

Comment: Not everyone encounters matrices before university.

Comment: Yes I know how to do this, but I think I need to use topology arguments to answer the question.

Comment: There's no way you're going to prove that matrix inversion is continuous using some kind of abstract topological argument.  You're showing that a specific function is continuous in a specific topology here, so you're going to have to use specific properties both of that function and of that topology.